# Pattern matching with unmatching interface does not generate a warning

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I stumbled across a missing warning when using the pattern matching feature of c#. Usually the compiler is very smart of detecting unreachable code, so I'm wondering why this will not generate a warning:

```
internal interface IAction{}
internal class Increment : IAction{}
internal class Decrement : IAction{}
internal class DoNothing{}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // obviously the following will not compile: 
        // Console.Write(Dispatch(5, new DoNothing()));
        Console.Write(Dispatch(5, new Increment()));
    }

    private static int Dispatch(int value, IAction action)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case Increment _:
                return value + 1;
            case Decrement _:
                return value - 1;
            case DoNothing _: // Not an IAction, will never happen, but no warning is generated
                return value;
            default:
                return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a `MyDoNothing` with

```
internal class MyDoNothing : DoNothing, IAction {}
```

It's both a `DoNothing` and an `IAction` and thus can be passed to your `Dispatch` method. If you seal the `DoNothing` class, then there will be a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

Each case statement is the equivalent of

```
if (action is SOMETHING)
```

action could well be a DoNothing and an IAction as follows:

```
public DoNothingEx : DoNothing, IAction{}
```